# MySQL triple join

Tags: mysql

Im having a hard time building the triple join query.

I have three tables:

**House:**

```
house ID(key) | Address | personID |
```

**Person:**

```
personID (key) | Name | Address |
```

**Images:** // of house

```
imageID (key) | personID | url |
```

I would like to limit the results to **5**.

I want to query house address-es (main), it's owner name & address, and one picture of the owner.

Note: There are up to 3 images of every person (3 rows in image table), but just one is necessary, doesnt matter which one.

Comment: a person can be owner of multiple houses? a person-row does only contain ONE house-id?!
how this will be possible?

Comment: Drop the house_id column from person and instead add a owner_id column to the house table, or probably better, create a owner_house table with owner_id, house_id columns.

Comment: @TheHe my mistake sorry, i fixed it.

Comment: @JamaicaBob an WHAT do you really want to query? a house for a person? all houses for a person? all houses with ONE image and the "owner"?

Comment: Ok sorry i fixed everything now. I want to query house address-es (main), it's owner name & address, and one picture of the owner. @TheHe

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
SELECT h.Address, p.Name, p.Address as OwnerAddress, i.url FROM house AS h
INNER JOIN person AS p ON p.personID = h.personID
INNER JOIN images AS i ON i.personID = p.personID
GROUP BY h.houseID
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it'd better for you to use LEFT OUTER JOIN, something like

```
SELECT
   h.Address  as `h_address`,
   p.Name     as `p_name`,
   p.Address  as `p_address`,
   i.url      as `i_url`
FROM house AS `h`
   LEFT OUTER JOIN person AS `p` ON (p.personID = h.personID)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN images AS `i` ON (p.personID = i.personID)
GROUP BY h.houseID
```

It would display also houses with no registered images.

Answer (score -1):

joining three tables

i.e:

```
select i_f.*, i_f_d.* , i_f_c.creator_name 
  from indent_form i_f 
  join indent_form_details i_f_d on i_f.id=i_f_d.ind_id 
  join indent_form_creator i_f_c on i_f.user_id=i_f_c.id

indent_form table 1,
indent_form_details table 2,
indent_form_creator table 3,
```